# WP Query Code to display unique div classes and WP Functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a WP Query code that will list all the post in my wordpress blog.

This code will be in a custom template under my created page in my wordpress blog.

The purpose of this wp query code is to display all post on a unique div classes and has a different html/php structure. For example, Post # 1 will display the title and the excerpt while the Post # 2 will display the title and the content and so on.

Below is the aforementioned code:

```
<?php /*** Template Name: Custom Page - Blog */ get_header(); ?>

<!-- START of WP Query -->

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array("post_type"=>'post')); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php $count++; ?>

<?php if ($count == 1) : ?>
<div class="item1">
    <span>Post 1 </span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# --> 

<?php elseif ($count == 2) : ?>      
<div class="item2">
<span>Post 2 </span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# --> 

<?php elseif ($count == 3) : ?>      
<div class="item3">
    <span>Post 3 </span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# --> 

<?php elseif ($count == 4) : ?>      
<div class="item4">
    <span>Post 4 </span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# --> 

<?php elseif ($count == 5) : ?>      
<div class="item5">
    <span>Post 5</span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->

<?php elseif ($count <= 7) : ?>      
<div class="item6">
    <span>Post 6 to 7 </span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->

<?php elseif ($count >= 8 && $count <= 16) : ?>      
<div class="item6">
    <span>Post 8 to 15 </span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->

<?php elseif ($count >= 17) : ?>      
<div class="item6">
    <span>Post 16 onwards - </span><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->


    <?php
    global $wp_query;

        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

        echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
        ) );
    ?>


<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- END of WP Query -->
```

The issue with the code above is its not properly displaying what I want. It displays the post # 1 to 5 but after that it doesnt follow the conditions `$count >= 5 || $count <= 7`, `$count >= 8 || $count <= 15`, `$count >= 8 || $count <= 15` and `$count >= 16`.

Also the code for numbered pagination doesn't work. It don't display anything:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
?>
```

Also, [here's the link](https://www.resumezilla.net/blog/) of my webpage so you can see what's happening when the code is implemented.

any ideas? any help that you can offer is very much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should be using `&&` for the second-to-last condition, otherwise it will be pulling in everything greater than 8 **OR** less than 15 (including the last condition of >= 16).  Try `<?php elseif ($count >= 8 && $count <= 15) : ?>`  Otherwise, please provide example data and the output that you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You should review [PHP Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).  The || operator in the `elseif ($count >= 5 || $count <= 7)` condition will pull anything >= 5 **OR** anything <=7, which is any and all numbers.  The same applies to the following condition with 8 and 15, so the following solution should fix your problem:

Post 1

```
<?php elseif ($count == 2) : ?>      
<div class="item2">
<span>Post 2</span><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_content(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# --> 

<?php elseif ($count == 3) : ?>      
<div class="item3">
    <span>Post 3</span><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_author(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# --> 

<?php elseif ($count == 4) : ?>      
<div class="item4">
    <span>Post 4</span><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# --> 

<?php elseif ($count == 5) : ?>      
<div class="item5">
    <span>Post 5</span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->

<?php elseif ($count >= 5 && $count <= 7) : ?>      
<div class="item6">
    <span>Post 6 to 7</span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->

<?php elseif ($count >= 8 && $count <= 15) : ?>      
<div class="item6">
    <span>Post 8 onwards - </span><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->

<?php elseif ($count >= 16) : ?>      
<div class="item6">
    <span>Post 8 onwards - </span><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->
```

**NOTE:** 
The better solution is to omit the second part of these comparisons, because we already know that it is >= 5 for the first one and >= 8 for the second one.  Easiest, cleanest solution looks like this:

```
...

<?php elseif ($count <= 7) : ?>      
<div class="item6">
    <span>Post 6 to 7</span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->

<?php elseif ($count <= 15) : ?>      
<div class="item6">
    <span>Post 8 onwards - </span><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->

...
```

---

---

---

**EDIT**
The question has changed, and the above code may hold some value, so I am keeping it, but the last two conditions should look like this:

**From the previous conditions, we already know that $count is >= 8, so removing that portion of the second-to-last condition will work fine:**

```
<?php elseif ($count <= 16) : ?>      
<div class="item6">
    <span>Post 8 to 16 </span><?php the_title(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->
```

**From the previous conditions, we already know that all remaining values for $count will be >= 17, so a simple 'else' will work fine:**

```
<?php else : ?>      
<div class="item6">
    <span>Post 16 onwards - </span><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .item# -->
```

Comment: I wanted to say that your thoughtful and well-written post was very helpful, and I appreciate what you do. Take my upvote!

Comment: thank you @mtr.web for your help. I've corrected the codes but there's still issues. the last three conditions $count >= 8 && $count >= 16 and $count > 17 doesn't work. It doesn't display the post # 16 onwards. What seems to be the problem? I have updated my codes from my question above.

Comment: @DanicaEscola, I edited the answer.  If it works for you, don't forget to accept/upvote.  Otherwise, let me know what is/isn't happening now, and I will edit the answer to fit.

Comment: I'm not sure why $count <= 16 is only displaying 3 post which in fact it should display post 8, 9, 10 to 16. what's the issue with $count <=16?